# How to tap on item in one controller and have it show in a different uicollectionviewcontroller class

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to tap on a collection view cell in one collection view controller and have it dynamically added to another collection view controller on same screen that when filled will turn into horizontal scrolling list of items. Similar to what is seen in the attached image of chickfila app when wanting to add pickles or bacon to order..

[image: chickfila app]

I have two different collection view controllers, one for the horizontal effect, shown on top of screen, and another controller showing the items that can be selected below. When I tap on items below I think I can get the array appended, but despite all kinds of reloadData calls, I can't get it to show this item in the horizontal controller above.. It doesn't seem to be calling didSelectItemAt again no matter what I do. I'm trying to do this just using the didSelectItemAt method.

Am I going about this totally wrong perhaps? I'm relatively new to the world of iOS programming. Thanks for any suggestions or help!!

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("tapped to add extra item somehow..")
    let selectedItem = indexPath.item
    if selectedItem >= 0 && indexPath.item < extras.count {
        super.extras.append(Extras(imageName: "bacon", calories: 100, price: 1, quantity: 1))
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

indexPath.index only gives you the index number in an array of element, and not the element(object) you are looking for.

You might wanna try something like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(arrayHoldingYourObjects[indexPath.item].id)
    collector.append(arrayHoldingYourObjects[indexPath.item])
    print("This is your colector \(collector)")
}

var collector: [Any] = []
```

Comment: I'm going to give that a try. I really hope it triggers the data source methods and reloads with correct info. Thanks!

Comment: It only gives you the selected element. This code works. I tested it myself.

Comment: ok that does the job of capturing the element selected and storing it. My problem is I am using the collector.count inside my IncludesController's numberOfItemsInSection method, but when I select the item with didSelectItemAt method inside the ExtrasController, it's not automatically updating the numberOfItemsInSection of the IncludesController. Does that make sense? I need to somehow trigger it to refresh the count and display the item using collector.count. Thanks again!! Really appreciate you giving it some thought!

Comment: maybe try collectionView.reloadData() inside wherever you need updates

Comment: I've tried that in so many ways and it doesn't seem to trigger the reload. I'm at a complete loss after staring at this problem for over a week. I feel it's something simple I'm probably overlooking. I don't know..

Comment: How are you adding data to Extras? Maybe this is empty and that's why collector.count is always empty... Try to print some values to console after fetching data. Are you getting something or is it nil?

Comment: var collector = [Extras]() {
    didSet {
        print("called after setting the new value")
    }
    willSet {
        print("called willSet")
        IncludesController().collectionView.reloadData()
    }
   
}

Comment: I am seeing the array count update but it's just not calling the numberOfItems method. I tried even to add a call to reloadData inside willSet property observer thinking that might be the trick.

Comment: Please build a mini project isolating the problem, post it to github and I'll take a look.

Comment: So you want to select a "bacon", and move it next to Chicken right?

Comment: Move an Item form ExtrasController to IncludesController, yes?

Comment: Sorry, if you look at the picture above, I want to tap on an Extras item (such as bacon) using the ExtraCollectionController didselectItemAt and then have it show in the Includes Controller, which will also allow a tap to remove as indicated.

Comment: Hey! What's up! I just finished the solution. It's up and running. I'll post the code on git and send you the link. It's probably not the best solution there is, but it sure works.

Comment: Great! looking forward to checking it out and learning something new! Appreciate it!

Comment: There you go: https://github.com/silviuisidor/transferCellBetweenUICollectionViews Let me know if that's what you're looking for.. All good?

Comment: You did it! I have a lot to learn with the Notification, batch update code. I think the only thing I would change is to somehow keep the Extra items below so the customer can just tap on it and it shows in the Includes controller. And if they tap on it again it keeps count of how many of that item is desired. I'll try to figure that out. Thanks for making my first experience on stackoverflow an awesome one! also love the values your company holds being a Christian myself. Remarkable looking website. Many thanks and cheers!

Comment: I'm glad it's been resolved. Drop me a line whenever you need any help. See you around on StackOverflow. See ya' P.S don't forget to thumbs up my answer